# unknown string format, python error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have Index like below:

```
Index(['2000-02-29 00:00:00_y', '2000-03-31 00:00:00_y',
       '2000-04-30 00:00:00_y', '2000-05-31 00:00:00_y',
       '2000-06-30 00:00:00_y', '2000-07-31 00:00:00_y',......
```

and tired to change in to datetime format by:

```
df.index.to_datetime())
```

now i am getting error :

```
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

slice the str to remove the extraneous `'_y'` and then convert:

```
In[123]:
pd.to_datetime(index.str[:-2])

Out[123]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2000-02-29', '2000-03-31', '2000-04-30', '2000-05-31',
               '2000-06-30', '2000-07-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Note that [`pd.Index.to_datetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html#pandas.Index.to_datetime) raises a `DeprecationWarning` so you should use the top-level [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) instead.

Note that by default the time component isn't displayed as it's equal to `'00:00:00'` but it is a full datetime:

```
In[124]:
pd.to_datetime(index.str[:-2])[0]

Out[124]: Timestamp('2000-02-29 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you @EdChum it helps :)